# MariaDB ALTER TABLE fails with integrity violation on unrelated index when upserts occur at the same time

Tags: mariadb

I have a table with a unique index that is used for upserts. The table contains ~ 500000 rows and is used by a scheduled job during which it experiences ~ 100 upsert queries by second. A schema change overlapped with the scheduled job and promptly failed with an integrity violation on the unique index.

I can reproduce the problem, but don't understand why it is happening? Apparently I'm not familiar enough with how MariaDB works under the hood, and reading the documentation does not answer my questions. I appreciate any pointers to better understand the situation.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy_table` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `a` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `b` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `c` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `d` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `AIDX` (`a`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `BIDX` (`b`, `c`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Upsert

```
INSERT INTO dummy_table (a, b, c, d) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d = NOW()');
```

Schema Change

```
ALTER TABLE dummy_table ADD e VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL AFTER c,
                DROP INDEX `BIDX`,
                ADD INDEX `BIDX` (`b`, `c`, `e`) USING BTREE;
```

Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'DUMMY_FILE_30361' for key 'AIDX'
```

Comment: There are no triggers regarding this table. The issue can be reproduced, your example does not insert hundreds of rows per second, let alone makes the schema change in parallel.

Comment: See if removing `AFTER c` avoids the integrity problem.  It _may_ at least run a lot faster.  And... Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: @DavidStrauß out of curiosity can you please try by [locking the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#sa33775040) ? In your case `SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES dummy_table WRITE;
ALTER TABLE dummy_table ADD e VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL AFTER c,DROP INDEX BIDX, ADD INDEX BIDX (b, c, e) USING BTREE;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;`

Comment: Version: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.19-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Removing the `AFTER` does not change the observed behavior but locking the table does indeed solve the problem. Do you have an idea why it is needed? To me, it seems that there is a short timespan where the uniqueness constraint is not enforced, which sounds bonkers.

Comment: @DavidStrauß it is not documented neither in MySQL or MariaDB documentation , based on my experience innodb tables always should be locked when altering. Maybe we need to file it as a bug or to be included in the documentation. This behaviour happens mostly on large tables in size or that have hughe amount of transactions